# Select constants from a list by propertyname

Tags: c#, properties

```
public class Constants
{
    public const string test1 = "This is testvalue1;"
    public const string test2 = "This is testvalue1;"
    public const string test3 = "This is testvalue1;"
    public const string test4 = "This is testvalue1;"
    public const string test5 = "This is testvalue1;"
}
```

is it in some way possible to get a constants string by usage of `var propertyString = Constants.Where(<Propertyname> == test1).ToString()` ?

Comment: You'd have to use reflection, but if you need to do such things, it's probably a better idea to use a static array or dictionary instead of individual constants.

Comment: Care to explain why it is better to use a static array?

Comment: See vc 74's answer ;-) Reflection is slower and is kind of a needless hack in your case, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to do this through reflection.

```
string fieldName = "test1";
object fieldValue = typeof(Constants).GetField(fieldName, BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(null);
```

Comment: Is there also a way to reverse this?  So I can find the propertyname by it's value?

Comment: Already found the answer to the question above: typeof<Constants>.GetFields().Where(m=> (string)m.GetValue(null) == "test1").First();

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to the other reflection oriented answers, you could use a dictionary:

```
public string GetConstantValue(string key)
{
  return _constants[key];
}

private Dictionary<string, string> Constants = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
  { "test1", "This is testvalue1;" },
  { "test2", "This is testvalue2;" },
  { "test3", "This is testvalue3;" },
  { "test4", "This is testvalue4;" },
  { "test5", "This is testvalue5;" },
};
```

And then use `MyClass.GetConstantValue("test1")` to get the constants value.

Answer (score 2):

This also could work:

```
    foreach (var prop in typeof(Constants).GetFields())
    {
        string test = prop.GetRawConstantValue().ToString();

        if (test == "test1")
            MessageBox.Show("You got me!");
    }
```

Comment: Can't really see the use for the first line. But yes, it works :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Reflection](http://ruscoweb.wordpress.com/2011/02/09/c-using-reflection-to-get-constant-values/).

```
List<string> messages = new List<string>();
foreach (FieldInfo field in typeof(Constants).GetFields().Where(f =>         f.Name.StartsWith("test")))
{
   messages.Add(field.GetRawConstantValue().ToString());

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get this,

```
var p = Constants.Get("test1");//gives 'This is testvalue1'
```

You can do this -

```
public class Constants
{
    public const string test1 = "This is testvalue1";
    public const string test2 = "This is testvalue1";
    public const string test3 = "This is testvalue1";
    public const string test4 = "This is testvalue1";
    public const string test5 = "This is testvalue1";

    public static string Get(string propertyName)
    {
      var value = (string)(typeof(Constants).GetField(propertyName,BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).GetValue(null));
      return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible. Following piece of code uses reflection to loop through all constants of a class.

```
internal class Program
{
    public const string ConstExample = "constant value";

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FieldInfo[] fieldInfos = typeof(Program).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);

        var constants = fieldInfos.Where(z => z.IsLiteral && !z.IsInitOnly).ToList();
        foreach (var constant in constants)
        {
            string constantName = constant.Name;
            object constantValue = constant.GetValue(null);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Constante name: {0}, constant value: {1}", constantName, constantValue));
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For good performance and readability I would recommend an array and an enumeration.

```
class App
{
    private enum ConstantsEnum: int
    {
      DefaultName = 0,
      DefaultMode = 1,
      DefaultStatus = 2
    }
    private readonly string[] Constants = new string[]{
        "MyProgram",
        "Test",
        "Enabled" };

    private void DoWork()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Constants[ConstantsEnum.DefaultName]);
    }
}
```

Note that all variables have to be of type `string`. If you want to mix and match datatypes then you could possibly use `object[]` instead of `string[]`, but this would be more expensive and not type-safe.

If you are just looking for a way to group some properties, then this is much better than reflection.